# What is a reliable way to specify a minimum pip version?

Tags: python, pip, pyproject.toml

What is a reliable way to specify the minimum required `pip` version in a project that uses `pyproject.toml`?

Is it:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64.0", "pip>=x.y"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

or should one put it into `requirements-dev.txt`?

or simply a `pip install --upgrade pip`, before installing the dev-requirements?

The background of the question is, I'm running tests across all main operating systems and Python versions. Some combinations fail because the pip version on the host machine is too old.

Comment: Why are you specifying pip inside the requirements.txt or .toml file exactly? 

requirements.txt or .toml file is used and prefixed with a pip command. it goes without saying, the user needs to have pip installed. these files only have the specific packages and their versions that are needed to make a script work. if you specify pip in there, you'll essentially telling the existing pip installed to add pip. so you're essentially trying to do `pip add pip` which I believe would error.

Or maybe I've completely misunderstood your question!

Comment: Not possible. *pip* maintainers only ever support the latest version of *pip*. It is assumed that everyone is responsible for keeping their *pip* up-to-date. So yes the correct way is to update pip before doing anything with pip. -- If your goal is to reproduce one specific behavior in your test processes (CI/CD pipelines?), then you can pin to a specific version of pip explicitly (`python -m pip install pip==X.Y.Z`).

Comment: @sinoroc that is interesting, do you have a source for the "pip maintainers only ever support the latest version of pip"? Cheers!

Comment: "_The latest version of the pip is the only supported version, previous versions should be considered unsupported. Users are encouraged to make regular updates to their version of pip in order to remain supported._" https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#supported-versions

Comment: I would say this also depends on your precise requirements. If the build (i.e. `setuptools` etc) won't work with an older version of `pip`, that's a build-time requirement; if your module itself needs a newer version of `pip`, that's a module dependency. Perhaps you can [edit] to clarify your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible.

Note that *pip* maintainers only ever support the latest version of pip. It is assumed that everyone is responsible for keeping their pip up-to-date. So yes the correct way is to update pip before doing anything with pip.

> The latest version of the pip is the only supported version, previous versions should be considered unsupported. Users are encouraged to make regular updates to their version of pip in order to remain supported.

-- https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#supported-versions

If your goal is to reproduce one specific behavior of a whole tool chain or workflow (including *pip*'s behavior) in your test processes (CI/CD pipelines?), then feel free to pin pip to a specific version explicitly (`python -m pip install pip==X.Y.Z`).

Of course, be also conscious that pip's maintainers are not perfect and each new release of pip is likely to contain some bugs. It has happened in the past that a new release of pip "broke" many a project's CI/CD pipeline. So pinning pip's version to a known but recent version is probably the best balance, with the inconvenient that this chosen pinned version itself must be updated once in a while (maybe at the earliest a few days after each new release of pip to avoid the possible new bugs).